# Can I run multiple instances of plank that only shows the current windows windows?

Tags: plank, window-management

I currently have 2 plank's running, but they show all of the workspaces current windows.

I need them to show only the current windows tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your settings for plank, there is an option, under the Behaviors tab that specifies: Restrict to Workspace, This may help you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, but I am after `window` not the workspace. I have 2 monitors and a plank on each monitor.

Comment: hmm strange, I also make use of two monitors and I only have plank active on my primary monitor. What I did was click on Desktop in my system settings, Click the dock tab, and switch primary display to on. Log out and log back in